# "Dominate" VS "Have control over"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference, verbs

According to the Cambridge definitions, [dominate someone / something](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dominate) means to have control over them. Accordingly, I think in my following cases, both sentences in each pair [mean the same](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/1079530). 
I was wondering if you could confirm my take on it approving this equality:

> **1)** She **dominates** her children. = She **has control over** her children. 
> **2)** He **dominates** his emotions. = He **has control over** his emotions. 
> **3)** He **dominates** the situation. = He **has control over** the situation.

I think they mean exactly the same thing with a slight nuance which strikes me that the cases with "dominate" are a bit more formal. However, I have no clue about their semantic prosody. Please let me know about it.

Answer (score 1):

*Dominate* does mean "to control", but it also implies that the control is oppressive, total, or tyrannical.

A mother who has control over her children doesn't let them play in a busy street, but one who dominates her children sounds like she doesn't let them do *anything* she doesn't want them to do. A man who has control over his emotions doesn't cry when watching a sad movie, but a man who has dominated his emotions sounds like a person who doesn't cry at his mother's funeral, or anywhere else.